# Ошибка при запуске команды gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Помогите понять и разобраться с истоками этой ошибки :
[image: Ошибка]

Код gulpfile.js

```js
let project_folder = "build";
let source_folder = "src";

/* пути к исходным файлам (src), к готовым файлам (build), а также к тем, за изменениями которых нужно наблюдать (watch) */
let path = {
    build: {
        html: project_folder + '/',
        css: project_folder + '/css/',
        js: project_folder + '/js/',
        img: project_folder + '/img/',
        fonts: project_folder + '/fonts/',
    },
    src: {
        html: source_folder + '/**/*.html',
        css: source_folder + '/scss/*.scss',
        js: source_folder + '/js/my.js',
        img: source_folder + '/img/*.jpg',
        fonts: source_folder + '/fonts/**/*.ttf',
    },
    watch: {
        html: source_folder + '/**/*.html',
        css: source_folder + '/**/*.scss',
        js: source_folder + '/**/*.js',
        img: source_folder + '/**/*.jpg'
    },
    clean: './' + project_folder + '/'
}

/* подключаем gulp и плагины */
let {src, dest} = require('gulp'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),  // подключаем Gulp
    browsersync = require('browser-sync').create(), // сервер для работы и автоматического обновления страниц

/* задачи */
function browserSync (params) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: './' + project_folder + '/' // Базовая папка, откуда будет запускаться browser-sync. Значение как для переменной clean
    },
    port: 3000,
    notify: false
  })
}

function html () {
    return src(path.src.html) // выбор всех html файлов по указанному пути
        .pipe(plumber()) // отслеживание ошибок
        .pipe(rigger()) // импорт вложений
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html)) // выкладывание готовых файлов
        .pipe(browsersync.stream()); // перезагрузка сервера
} 

let build = gulp.series(html);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build,browserSync);

exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* подключаем gulp и плагины */
let {src, dest} = require('gulp'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),  // подключаем Gulp
    browsersync = require('browser-sync').create(),
//                                                ^
//                                         Лишняя запятая
```

Comment: Частично разобрался,все дело было в отсутствии доп плагинов в файле gulpfile.js. Однако при запуске команды .pipe(browsersync.stream()) открывается браузер с надписью Cannot GET /